# Is it possible to pass intent by intent?

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I want to pass something like this, is it possible? or how can I do that in some other way?
If you don't know, pop up thread.
Thank you for your time.

What i want to achieve:

I want to change visibility of button depending on list in MyClassAdapter. Becouse in one activity i add some stuff button shows up and were going to next activity and for example remove some stuff from list, returning back to previous activity and now button is visible, i want to make it uvisible.

Here is my code :

```
Intent i = new Intent(getContext(),MyClassAdapter.class);
i.putExtras(button_submit.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE));
```

Here is my error:

```
The method putExtras(Intent) in the type Intent is not applicable for the arguments (void)
```

Comment: What *exactly* is it that you want to achieve?

Comment: Serializable ?????????? public void putSerializable (String key, Serializable value)

Comment: button_submit.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE) doesn't have a return valid, that is why it is 'void'.

Comment: @codeMagicI want to change visibility of button depending on list in MyClassAdapter. Becouse in one activity i add some stuff button shows up and were going to next activity and for example remove some stuff from list, returning back to previous activity and now button is visible, i want to make it uvisible.

Answer (score 3):

```
final String VISIBILITY_EXTRA = "viewVisibility";
```

Pass an int,

```
Intent i = new Intent(getContext(),MyClassAdapter.class);
i.putExtra(VISIBILITY_EXTRA,View.VISIBLE);
```

While receiving it,

```
int visibility = intent.getIntExtra(VISIBILITY_EXTRA);
```

If you're trying to pass a view, its one of the bad ways. Use fragments instead.

Comment: i've got error VISIBILITY_EXTRA cannot be resolved to a variable

Comment: Edited. Declaring the variable.

Comment: I have to cast it to Object and then i got error like this: The method putInt(String, int) is undefined for the type Object

Comment: Intent allows you to pass integers, you don't have to cast it to object. What exactly are you trying to achieve. May be you should rethink your architecture design.

Answer (score 1):

I am not really sure what you're trying to achieve, but you can't do:

```
i.putExtras(button_submit.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE));
```

as method `View#setVisibility` is of return type `void`.

Comment: i've edited post also my error is : The method putExtras(Intent) in the type Intent is not applicable for the arguments (void)

Comment: @user3299430 yeah the error is clear, the real question is what is it you're trying to achieve.. If the visibility depends on some list, then maybe you should rather gain access to that list, instead of trying to put Adapter into intent (which probably isn't even an Activity class).